# I can not get rid of the markers that was created in the last call to map bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-plugins

I load my google map with some markers and then when user click the date buttom I load it again and it works properly and my code is  as follow:

```
  function maptest(){

 $('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers');
 demo.add(function () {

     $('#map_canvas').gmap('destroy');
     $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'zoom': 3, 'disableDefaultUI': true }).bind('init', function (evt, map) {

         var bounds = map.getBounds();
         var mark1 = "hello";
         var mark2 = "bye";
         var temp = mark1;
         var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
         var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
         var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
         var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
         for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
             if (i % 2 === 0) {
                 temp = mark2;
             }
             else {
                 temp = mark1;
             }
             var contentString = 'test';
             $(this).gmap('addMarker',
        {'id':'markers', 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(
           southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
           southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random()),
            'content': contentString
        }
      ).click(function (i) {
          $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
              content: this.content
          }, this);
      });
         }
         $(this).gmap('set', 'MarkerClusterer', new MarkerClusterer(map, $(this).gmap('get', 'markers')));
     });
 }).load();
```

}

Now my problem is that after each time that I click date  button which invokes maptest function the markers that was made before does not disappear and the number of markers gets doubles but I want just the markers for the new call to maptest() function. Can anyone guide me what is wrong with my code that I get duplication?

**Last Update of my code according to suggestions:**

```
var markers = [];
var j = 0;
 $(function () {
$("#tt").click(function () {
    clearMarkers1();
    maptest();
});
$('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'zoom': 3, 'disableDefaultUI': true }).bind('init', function (evt, map) {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
    var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var $marker = $(this).gmap('addMarker',
                    {
                        'id': i, 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(
                        southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
                        southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random()),
                        'content': 'm_' + i
                    }).click(function (i) {
                        $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                            content: this.content
                        }, this);
                    });
        markers.push($marker); // add to the marker array
    }
    j = j + 3;
    $(this).gmap('set', 'MarkerClusterer', new MarkerClusterer(map, $(this).gmap('get', 'markers')));
});
});


 function clearMarkers1() {

   for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
      alert("clear : "+i);
       if(typeof $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'markers')[i]!='undefined' )
         {
           $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'markers')[i].setMap(null);
         }

  }

  }
function maptest() 
{
  $('#map_canvas').gmap('destroy');
  $('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'zoom': 3, 'disableDefaultUI': true }).bind('init', function (evt, map) 
 {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
    var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
    for (var i = j; i < j + 3; i++) {
        var contentString = 'bgg';
        var $marker = $(this).gmap('addMarker',
                    {
                        'id': i, 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(
                        southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
                        southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random()),
                        'content': 'm_' + i
                    }).click(function (i) {
                        $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                            content: this.content
                        }, this);
                    });
        markers.push($marker); // add to the marker array
    }
    j = j + 3;
    $(this).gmap('set', 'MarkerClusterer', new MarkerClusterer(map, $(this).gmap('get', 'markers')));
});
}
```

My problem is solve the only error that I get is this:

[image]

```
    $(this).gmap('set', 'MarkerClusterer', new MarkerClusterer(map, $(this).gmap('get',   'markers')));
```

Comment: `.off('click').click(function (i) {...});` ??? Or just don't nest this handler

Comment: Please see the update : my datebutton is not simply a button it is a plug in. Can I use the way you suggested in this case?

Comment: You could use namespaced event: `.off('click.anyNamespace').on('click.anyNamespace', function (i) {...});`. Now you have to do some test

Comment: Sorry that I am asking too many questions but I did not really get that how can I use it in the above scenario when I have onClose:...?

Comment: @A. Wolff I did what you did with simple button but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by removing the usage of the methods of the `demo`-object. This object and it's methods are used by the example-pages for `jquery-ui-map` for displaying the demos and are not a part of this library.

Each time you call maptest the function passed as argument to `demo.add` will be pushed onto a stack, and when you call `demo.load` all these functions will be executed.

---

related to the specific issue:

When you inspect the map you'll recognize that the previous markers have been removed successfully, but on each call you get 3 markers more.

In `maptest()` you first `destroy` the map(what removes the markers), and then you re-initialize the map and bind the `init`-listener.

But: the `init`-listener isn't bounded to the map, it's bounded to `$('#map-canvas')` , and it will never be removed, so on each call of `maptest` you add 1 more `init`-listener.

Solution: use `one()` to add the listener, then the listener will be removed when he has been executed:

```
function maptest(){
  $('#map-canvas')
   .gmap('destroy') //this will remove the markers
    .gmap({'zoom': 2, 'disableDefaultUI':true})
      .one('init', function() {
        var map        = $(this).gmap('get','map'),
            bounds     = map.getBounds(),
            southWest  = bounds.getSouthWest()
            northEast  = bounds.getNorthEast(),
            lngSpan    = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng(),
            latSpan    = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();

           for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
              var lat = southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random()
              lng = southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random();
              $('#map-canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
                           'ID':'m'+i ,
                           'position': new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng) 
                        }).click(function() {
                            $('#map-canvas')
                             .gmap('openInfoWindow', 
                                   { content : 'Hello world!' }, 
                                   this);
                        });
           }

         $('#map-canvas')
        .gmap('set', 
              'MarkerClusterer', 
              new MarkerClusterer(map, $(this).gmap('get', 'markers')));
     });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a million Dr.Molle for your answer  I did what you said but even when I clear the markers and add new ones still the last deleted markers appears, I also updated the last version of my code above . I am so confused. I appreciate any help:)

Comment: Thanks a million yes it worked and you helped me a lot. Now I understand why you have that much reputation:) but just a tiny error that I get: at loading time it is ok but when I call maptest I get that error(You can see it in my updated post above and when I remove the assigning id I dont get that error anymore, do you have any idea what is this error?

Comment: Please create a fiddle that exhibits the issue, I did not get ay errors with my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure how your code is working without seeing the whole thing, but I have modified some of what you have to keep track of the added markers in an array.

First, add an array to store markers outside your function:

```
var markers = [];
```

Second, modify the way you add markers slightly

```
var $marker = $(this).gmap('addMarker',
{
id: 'm_' + i, 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(
    southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
    southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random()),
'content': contentString
}
```

Then push each marker to the array:

```
   ).click(function (i) {
      $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
       content: this.content
     }, this);
   });
     markers.push($marker); // add to the marker array
   }
```

I added a function to clear the markers from the map that are in the array, then clear the array

```
        function clearMarkers(callback) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'markers')['m_' + i].setMap(null);
            }
            markers.length = 0;
            callback();
        }
```

Then I just call clear markers with a callback to your now modified maptest() function:

```
                clearMarkers(function () {
                    maptest();
                });
```

Comment: I guess you mean  this line of code  $('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers'); but it does not work!

Comment: Are you using jquery-ui-map? I am making assumptions here and I don't see anything in the code you posted that shows where you clear markers. See my edited answer.

Comment: I am using google map Api(clustering version) : http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-basic-example.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, here is the result: if I do not use destroy method this approach works and clear all the markers but then  callback to maptest never shows any markers again and map is out of markers,if I use destroy then clear method works and exactly after calling maptest it double again the number of markers! Thanks a lot for your awesome help but what is your idea now?

Comment: FYI,I guess the link that I posted above is not correct and I am using this version of google map: http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-clustering.html