# map does not cluster locations as soon as I add id to markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-plugins

it is around a week that I am fighting with google map to add it to my peoject.
I need to use this google map:
http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-clustering.html

as far as I use the code in that link everything is good but as soon as I add id to each marker that I am creating clustering does not work anymore. Here is my code:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({'zoom': 2, 'disableDefaultUI':true}).bind('init', function(evt, map) { 
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('clear', 'markers');

                    var bounds = map.getBounds();
                    var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
                    var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
                    var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
                    var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
                    for ( var i = 0; i <2; i++ ) {
                        $(this).gmap('addMarker', {'id':'m_'+i, 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(), southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random()) } ).click(function() {
                            $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { content : 'ddd d!' }, this);
                        });
                    }
                    $(this).gmap('set', 'MarkerClusterer', new MarkerClusterer(map, $(this).gmap('get', 'markers')));
                });
```

As you can see I just added some  id's to each markers that I am using. FYI, I need to add id because later I want to remove markers when for example a button is clicked and add new markers after clicking.

Can anyone help me how to add id to markers in a way that I do not loose  clustering property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` of a marker is used internally by jquery-ui-map to identify a marker in the markers-**array** . Note that `markers`initially is an array. It's possible to use a custom `id` , but the id should be numeric(array-keys may only be numeric ).

In your case it's a string, what will convert the array into an object. The MarkerClusterer-version used in the linked demo is 2.0.6 which requires markers to be an array, not an object, because it iterates by using the length-property(which is not present for an object)

Solutions: use a newer version, e.g. 2.1.1 , or another name for the property(for example `ID` )

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I have a big problem in the following link can you please take look and guid me (actually this question was related to that question  and I am  totally stuck)                     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616455/i-can-not-get-rid-of-the-markers-that-was-created-in-the-last-call-to-map-bind